# Inline CSS background image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner with regards to CSS and HTML but have searched everywhere for a solution to this and still have no idea what is going on.

I am attempting to create a background image with a logo/subtitle on top of it. Although only the subtitle and `alt` text is showing up. I have gone over the syntax multiple times and am still unsure of where the error is as I am declaring the correct css specifications from what I can tell.

#HTML:

```
<div class="blog-type-wrapper">
        <div class="blog-type-img-background" style="background-image:url(images/software.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="img-text-wrapper">
          <div class="logo-wrapper">
            <img src="images/software-logo.png" alt="soft">
          </div>
          <div class="subtitle">
            Software N Stuff
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

#CSS

```
.blog-type-img-background{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

There is space on the web page allocated to the image, however no images appear. The images are in another folder named "images" in the same directory as both the html and css files. This is occurring in a PHP file, I have attempted researching if that makes a difference in comparison to HTML file, and have found nothing but I cannot see how it would make a difference with regards to this issue.

**Edit**
The file path was incorrect. Thank you to @Heretic Monkey and others

"Look at the Networking tab of your browser's developer tools and look for any errors, like a 404 with the image's file name. That will show the full URL to the image it's trying to load. It's likely incorrect, relative to the HTML file. Fix that"

After looking in the networking tab I realized that my file path was incorrect and changing it to style="background-image:url(wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/software.jpg)"> worked in loading the image as expected.

Comment: Change this `background-image:url(images/software.jpg)` to this `background-image:url("images/software.jpg")`. I have wrapped it in a quotation marks. Let us know the result.

Comment: If you say that also the regular image (logo) doesn't show, but the alt-text instead, it seems that the filepath isn't correct so that both images aren't found.

Comment: Look at the Networking tab of your browser's developer tools and look for any errors, like a 404 with the image's file name. That will show the full URL to the image it's trying to load. It's likely incorrect, relative to the HTML file. Fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Source should contain either `/`, `./`, or `../`:

In case the image folder is in the absolute root path, you should use `/images/image.png`

If it's in the same directory as the current file's location, then use `./images/image.png`

If it's in an upper folder, use `../images/image.png`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
style="background-image:url(images/software-logo.png)"
```

to

```
style="background-image: url('images/software-logo.png');"
```

Also, depending on where your images folder is located, you might need a `/` before, like this: `/images/software-logo.png`.

The result would be this:

```
<div class="blog-type-wrapper">
  <div class="blog-type-img-background" style="background-image: url('images/software-logo.png');"></div>
  <div class="img-text-wrapper">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
      <img src="images/software-logo.png" alt="soft">
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      Software N Stuff
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still valid without quotes wrapping the URL, so that isn't likely to be the issue. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url)